# Using CryptoJS to decrypt a ciphertext from openssl_seal

Tags: javascript, php, openssl, cryptography, cryptojs

I need to encode message with PHP using public key and decode this message with javascript using private key.

This is test code:

```
<?php
$message = 'sevenflash';

$public_key = openssl_get_publickey(file_get_contents('pubkey.pem'));

$encrypted = $e = NULL;
openssl_seal($message, $encrypted, $e, array($public_key));

$sealed_data = base64_encode($encrypted);
$envelope = base64_encode($e[0]);

$unsealed = null;
openssl_open(base64_decode($sealed_data), $unsealed, base64_decode($envelope), file_get_contents('privatekey.pem'));
echo $unsealed; // This is sevenflash

$embed = "<script>var encrypted = '$sealed_data'; var envelope = '$envelope'; </script>";
?>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="rc4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="enc-base64.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jsencrypt/bin/jsencrypt.js"></script>
    <?php echo $embed; ?>
    <script>
        var private_key = `...`;

        var crypt = new JSEncrypt();
        crypt.setPrivateKey(private_key);
        var theKey = crypt.decrypt(envelope);

        var decrypted = CryptoJS.RC4.decrypt(encrypted, theKey);
        console.log(decrypted.toString()); // This must be sevenflash, but this is 696a2b0440220d69e8c3
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

But this doesn't work. Why?

Comment: Private key in JS loaded via browser? What's the point of doing anything if private key is visible to everyone? Don't you think that PHP should have the private key and JS should have public key?

Comment: Client has a certificate with private and public key. Public key sends to server. Server encrypt message for client and save it to database. Client receive a message and using private key decrypt this message. This private key will be retrieved from .pem file stored on client side. Why this key will be visible for everyone?

Comment: @N.B. I guess the OP wants to say that the private key is hard coded for testing purposes, but will be kept strictly at client side (e.g. localStorage) once the encryption and decryption works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CryptoJS decryption expects a `CipherParams` object in place of the ciphertext and a `WordArray` in place of the key. If you pass in the key as a string, then it will assume that it is a password and try to derive a key from that with MD5 and a non-existent salt.

Try to parse everything:

```
var decrypted = CryptoJS.RC4.decrypt({
    ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(encrypted)
}, CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse(theKey));
```

JSEncrypt returns a "plain string" from the `crypt.decrypt()` function, which means that it has to be either parsed with Latin1 or UTF-8 encoding in mind.
But I couldn't make it work with JSEncrypt, so I used [forge](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge) instead:

```
var privateKey = forge.pki.privateKeyFromPem(private_key);
var theKey = privateKey.decrypt(forge.util.decode64(envelope), 'RSAES-PKCS1-V1_5');
```

CrypoJS' `.toString()` returns a Hex-encoded version by default. You can override that to get textual data:

```
console.log(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

```js
var private_key = `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`;

var encrypted = 'E+moZJOeVuxgsg=='; var envelope = 'LMJqdAu+FVPxVpVkLgBOrqLWkY/S/56KHETnt528k2D0lUDzl7nymsgycrto5BD4w17oH6THyC+0yg/‌​Ws+gqpIIWimcQze1KKQy+1+uvH4gR1Olt22cgEUDid09dDqvSXi0VcYYYQXyxWzIQVd2Jun1A0h1qhWc4‌​LinzkJSP6HuhH+D52eEcXep5H4cjjy62rgGIR5YyQO/RBXuYYBBRSgmeniFjY9FbR8AaBkhcCVYeBH28u‌​Bi0dx27hPQ0yVlVWrG3KuR2i441Ruhb4J+AOnr+K1uIMT+rnk8Th8eTTc/E1CSrZo9GASfEyYK8mJdwfq‌​2/FJ5Qnp9uHl1aN/1RSg==';

var privateKey = forge.pki.privateKeyFromPem(private_key);
var theKey = privateKey.decrypt(forge.util.decode64(envelope), 'RSAES-PKCS1-V1_5');

var decrypted = CryptoJS.RC4.decrypt({
    ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(encrypted)
}, CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse(theKey));
console.log(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/CryptoStore/crypto-js/3.1.2/build/rollups/rc4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/CryptoStore/crypto-js/3.1.2/build/components/enc-base64-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/artjomb/96b970358e20410fa64daa2e844aeb0f/raw/5375e7171ef297d436d65b962149dcc0e1960b2b/forge_v0.6.39.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Error: Malformed UTF-8 data

Comment: Can you provide an example private key and ciphertext? I'd like to try some things out.

Comment: [https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3AEiFiqUYxPNS1QOU1iVk94Nkk/view?usp=sharing] [https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3AEiFiqUYxPSHo4UEQzTUNab00/view?usp=sharing]
In fact, openssl_open works right with this keys in test code.

Comment: I'll look into it tomorrow. Can you show some example `encrypted` and `envelope` values?

Comment: <script>var encrypted = 'E+moZJOeVuxgsg=='; var envelope = 'LMJqdAu+FVPxVpVkLgBOrqLWkY/S/56KHETnt528k2D0lUDzl7nymsgycrto5BD4w17oH6THyC+0yg/Ws+gqpIIWimcQze1KKQy+1+uvH4gR1Olt22cgEUDid09dDqvSXi0VcYYYQXyxWzIQVd2Jun1A0h1qhWc4LinzkJSP6HuhH+D52eEcXep5H4cjjy62rgGIR5YyQO/RBXuYYBBRSgmeniFjY9FbR8AaBkhcCVYeBH28uBi0dx27hPQ0yVlVWrG3KuR2i441Ruhb4J+AOnr+K1uIMT+rnk8Th8eTTc/E1CSrZo9GASfEyYK8mJdwfq2/FJ5Qnp9uHl1aN/1RSg=='; </script>

Comment: But on every page refresh this is different values.

Comment: Thanks, it looks to me that JSBN's UTF-8 encoding is not really standards-conform. It is part of the `pkcs1unpad2` (called at the end of `decrypt`) in [rsa2.js](https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt/blob/master/lib/jsbn/rsa2.js), which is part of jsencrypt.js

Comment: You have basically two options: a) Remove the broken UTF-8 encoding from `pkcs1unpad2` and instead returns the byte array; then convert the byte array into CryptoJS' `WordArray` (a word consists of 4 bytes). b) Don't use `openssl_seal` and instead do your own symmetric key generation and encryption; then you can encode (Base64, Hex, etc.) the symmetric key prior to encryption and then you can be sure to get correct values fron JSEncrypt's `decrypt` function.

Comment: I would prefer option (a)

Comment: function pkcs1unpad2(d,n) {
  return d.toByteArray();
}
How to convert this byte array to word array?

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/7ef1ee574a411ba0dd1933c1ef4690d1) is a way.

Comment: The same Error: Malformed UTF-8 data

Comment: Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I couldn't make it work with JSEncrypt, so I simply used forge and it worked at first time. Have a look at the full example at the end of my answer.

Comment: Thanks you very much for explanation and working example! 
You are the best in field of javascript encryption!